# I want to JSON Parse an array of objects inside an object - articles from the body, how can I do that?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, alan

I am making an api request in Alan studio and the news api returns an object from which I want to parse "articles" and store it and send them to my react code for displaying them on the news cards

*But when I parse articles from the body, articles is becoming undefined.How can I JSON parse it?*

Given below is the data returned from news api.

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "totalResults": 10,
    "articles": [
        {
            "source": {
                "id": "bbc-news",
                "name": "BBC News"
            },
            "author": "BBC News",
            "title": "Monkeypox: Nigeria bans bushmeat to prevent virus spread",
            "description": "Experts say it is possible that the virus can be caught by eating meat from an infected animal.",
            "url": "http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-africa-61676841",
            "urlToImage": "https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/branded_news/983B/production/_125017983_gettyimages-453645236.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2022-06-02T17:22:28.5473137Z",
            "content": "By Chris EwokorBBC News, Abuja\r\nImage caption, Bushmeat is a delicacy in parts of Nigeria, but in other places it can be a vital source of food\r\nThe Nigerian government has banned the sale of bushmea… [+2373 chars]"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": "bbc-news",
                "name": "BBC News"
            },
            "author": "BBC News",
            "title": "Ukraine war: Zelensky says Russia controls a fifth of Ukrainian territory",
            "description": "Ukraine's president says Russia has taken 20% of Ukraine's territory, as the war nears its 100th day.",
            "url": "http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-europe-61675915",
            "urlToImage": "https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/branded_news/130F7/production/_125017087_hi076131363.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2022-06-02T17:22:24.7575621Z",
            "content": "By Matt MurphyBBC News\r\nImage caption, A Russian soldier in Mariupol\r\nUkraine's President Volodymyr Zelensky says that Russian forces have seized 20% of his country's territory, as Moscow's invasion … [+5338 chars]"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": "bbc-news",
                "name": "BBC News"
            },
            "author": "BBC News",
            "title": "Oklahoma hospital shooting: Five dead after gunman targets physician",
            "description": "Police say the man blamed the doctor for his back pain and had purchased a rifle only hours earlier.",
            "url": "http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-61676811",
            "urlToImage": "https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/branded_news/1307/production/_125017840_gettyimages-1241045718.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2022-06-02T16:52:23.4616839Z",
            "content": "Image source, Getty Images\r\nImage caption, Police respond to the scene of Wednesday's shooting at St Francis Hospital\r\nPolice have said a gunman who killed three employees and a patient at an Oklahom… [+2376 chars]"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": "bbc-news",
                "name": "BBC News"
            },
            "author": "BBC News",
            "title": "Canada says China 'buzzing' military flights in Asia",
            "description": "Canada called the incidents are unprofessional and potentially hazardous to aircrew in the Pacific.",
            "url": "http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-61654043",
            "urlToImage": "https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/branded_news/75B3/production/_125013103_gettyimages-1341999649.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2022-06-02T13:37:19.2266278Z",
            "content": "By Bernd Debusmann JrBBC News, Washington\r\nImage source, Getty Images\r\nImage caption, Chinese military aircraft at an airshow in September 2021\r\nCanadian military aircraft operating in Asia have been… [+2007 chars]"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": "bbc-news",
                "name": "BBC News"
            },
            "author": "BBC News",
            "title": "Depp-Heard trial: Why Johnny Depp lost in the UK but won in the US",
            "description": "Experts say key factors included having a jury trial and his lawyers using a specific legal tactic.",
            "url": "http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-61673676",
            "urlToImage": "https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/branded_news/6037/production/_125013642_gettyimages-1241024662.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2022-06-02T12:22:23.3055092Z",
            "content": "By Robin Levinson-KingBBC News\r\nImage source, Getty Images\r\nIn 2020, Hollywood actor Johnny Depp lost a UK libel lawsuit against the Sun newspaper. But on Wednesday, he won a similar lawsuit against … [+2956 chars]"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": "bbc-news",
                "name": "BBC News"
            },
            "author": "BBC News",
            "title": "Turkey wants be be called Türkiye in rebranding move",
            "description": "The country wants to be called Türkiye as part of a rebranding campaign launched by its president.",
            "url": "http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-europe-61671913",
            "urlToImage": "https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/branded_news/17CDD/production/_125010579_bluemosquegetty.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2022-06-02T11:07:25.2572035Z",
            "content": "Image source, @MevlutCavusoglu\r\nImage caption, Turkish Foreign Minister Mevlut Cavusoglu\r\nTurkey will be known as Türkiye at the United Nations from now on, after it agreed to a formal request from A… [+1736 chars]"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": "bbc-news",
                "name": "BBC News"
            },
            "author": "BBC News",
            "title": "Texas school shooting victim's parents mourn 'best friend'",
            "description": "The parents of Alithia Ramirez say they want the world to remember their daughter through her art.",
            "url": "http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-61669234",
            "urlToImage": "https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/branded_news/11FC6/production/_125007637_p0cbl2cx.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2022-06-02T10:07:17.1192126Z",
            "content": "Last week 10-year-old Alithia Ramirez was shot and killed when a gunman opened fire at her primary school in Uvalde, Texas. \r\nHer parents say they want the world to remember their daughter was good a… [+168 chars]"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": "bbc-news",
                "name": "BBC News"
            },
            "author": "BBC News",
            "title": "Bill Cosby 'pounced' on teen in Playboy Mansion",
            "description": "The comedian's lawyers dismiss the latest claim against him - stemming from 1975 - as a \"fabrication\".",
            "url": "http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-61664500",
            "urlToImage": "https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/branded_news/64DC/production/_125002852_gettyimages-1040552476.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2022-06-02T07:37:18.1596491Z",
            "content": "Image source, Getty Images\r\nImage caption, Bill Cosby at his sentencing in Pennsylvania in 2018\r\nLess than a year after his sex assault conviction was thrown out and he walked free from prison, comed… [+2473 chars]"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": "bbc-news",
                "name": "BBC News"
            },
            "author": "BBC News",
            "title": "Queen’s Platinum Jubilee: Trooping the Colour to begin celebrations",
            "description": "The Queen's Birthday Parade will kick off four days of celebrating the monarch's 70-year reign.",
            "url": "http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/live/uk-61516564",
            "urlToImage": "https://m.files.bbci.co.uk/modules/bbc-morph-news-waf-page-meta/5.2.0/bbc_news_logo.png",
            "publishedAt": "2022-06-02T06:07:24.9486456Z",
            "content": "Trooping the Colour is an annual military parade that marks the Queens official birthday - which this year falls on 11 June (her actual birthday is 21 April).\r\nThis is a centuries-old tradition which… [+973 chars]"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": "bbc-news",
                "name": "BBC News"
            },
            "author": "BBC News",
            "title": "Depp-Heard trial: Jury sides mostly with Depp in defamation case",
            "description": "Jurors award Mr Depp $15m in compensatory and punitive damages, but also award Ms Heard $2m.",
            "url": "http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-61668780",
            "urlToImage": "https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/branded_news/12926/production/_125007067_tv076335814.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2022-06-02T01:37:20.4013741Z",
            "content": "Media caption, Watch: Depp v Heard defamation case concludes in court\r\nA US jury has found Amber Heard defamed ex-husband Johnny Depp with an article in which she claimed she was a victim of domestic… [+4697 chars]"
        }
    ]
}
```

```js
// News by Source
intent('Give me the news from $(source* (.*))', (p) => {
    let NEWS_API_URL = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines`;
    
    if(p.source.value) {
        NEWS_API_URL = `${NEWS_API_URL}?sources=${p.source.value.toLowerCase().split(" ").join('-')}&apiKey=${API_KEY}`;
    }

    api.request(NEWS_API_URL, (error, response, body) => {
        const { articles } = JSON.parse(body);
        
        console.log(articles); // returns undefined
        
        if(articles?.length === 0) {
            p.play('Sorry, please try searching for news from a different source');
            return;
        }
        
        savedArticles = articles;
        
        p.play({ command: 'newHeadlines', articles });
        p.play(`Here are the (latest|recent) ${p.source.value}.`);
  
        p.play('Would you like me to read the headlines?');
        p.then(confirmation);
    });
})
```

Comment: What is `body`? Please check it's what you expect

Comment: if articles is undefined, then the json you parsed didn't contain an articles key at the top level. There is no other explanation. It is undefined, the error is correct. Check your data.

Comment: @KevinB, yes, my question is how can I fetch it in a variable?

Comment: @evolutionxbox, according to alan docs, this is the way of making an api request. An example is 
const SERVICE_URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather";
 const appid = "4acdb6432d18884ebc890c13a9c3cc85";

 intent('What is the weather in $(LOC)', p => {
     const request_url = `${SERVICE_URL}?appid=${appid}&q=${p.LOC}&units=imperial`;
     api.request(request_url, (error, res, body) => {
         if (error || res && res.statusCode !== 200) {
             p.play('Could not get weather information');
         } else {
             }

Comment: Sure, but what is the actual response and is it what you expect?

Comment: well, if your data was as you said it was, your code would work. So something you've described isn't correct.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the API request is expecting a promise to return from the API call, here is a quick code snippet that is working and returning data (just replace your API key in the URL.

```js
// API CALL START HERE
let data = fetch("https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=<your api key here>")
    .then(function(response) {
    // This returns the promise from the API request which processes the data
    return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(data) {
        // Loop through the data returned for articles and console log each specific article
        for (const article in data.articles ) {
          console.log(data.articles[article]);
        }
    });
```